# Clearing house on Facebook - Deleting everything

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a Facebook bot that will delete everything that I have created: photos, messages, comments, shares, likes and anything else.

What language should I use and how should I start?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want to code that kind of application. You just need their API and a lot of permissions so you're able to list them and delete then one by one. But why not just [deactivate](https://www.facebook.com/deactivate.php) your account?

You will never manage to delete any content on Facebook, everything is just hidden

Comment: @GoofBall: They will never delete any of your data, even if you think you will

Comment: @moguzalp: I didn't get you. Facebook just changes "deleted" column to 1 or moves your record (deleted) to another table, but they don't delete it

Comment: @moguzalp: I'm not an employee, so I can't know this, but yes, it is possible

Comment: @Goof I hope you read their Terms of use (I know you didn't...), it says they can do everything they want to do with your details...

Comment: @GoofBall: As I said, it doesn't make sense. They will do not delete it

Answer (score 0):

In general, applications using the API can only delete content that they've created. I.e your app can only delete a photo if it was uploaded using your app.

As a side note, If you want to purge your entire account, why not just delete the entire thing? It's the first result  in the help centre for 'delete account'  I don't understand why you believe Facebook won't delete your account manually (which they will), but think that doing it via the API would work (it also would, apart from the permissions issue i mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of genesis that Facebook won't delete your data ever, they will just keep it hidden. But my approach would be to make a userscript which you run in your own browser (so short answer is javascript) and just trigger actions as if you were doing that manually. Also take care not to load too many pages too quick, Facebook monitors that. Put some delay after, lets say 2-3 sec after a delete action.

Earlier http://suicidemachine.org/ supported doing that for you, but Facebook banned their service. They should have made their code public so that anyone can run it on their own but then things might have changed and it would need to be maintained to always work but yeah something on github would have been great :D

Comment: Same comment as my own answer; i don't understand why someone would not trust Facebook to delete the data when asked to, but would trust that clicking the 'delete' button in the web interface will work - the cognitive dissonance here is very confusing to me

Comment: Read this http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/10/21/facebook-privacy-policy-europe-student-complaints_n_1022988.html